# Why String hashCode doesn't have size limitation?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

It bugs me for a while but I didn't find any convincing answer yet, so why `hashCode` function in Java String doesn't have any size limitation? Below is implementation which I found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java):

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

First of all I understand usage of temp variable `h` which makes sense when using String in multiple threads. Secondly we all know that above implementation **can't avoid hash collisions** (none hashCode implementation can), so basically we should treat this function as "performance improvement" only, which is useful for hash tables or similar structures.

If so, then why allowing situation where we have e.g. 100 MB String and we compute hash basing on **all** it's chars? Wouldn't it make more sense to add some limit? 32 / 128 maybe even 1024 chars but not whole value.length? Yes if we would have two different Strings with the same prefix which is as long as our limit then we would have hash collision but **we can't avoid collisions anyway**, so from performance point of view I would personally change for loop to something like:

```
int limit = value.length > 32 ? 32 : value.length;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    h = 31 * h + val[i];
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: The answer is: ... *drum roll* ... only the java devs know. Also the whole computation is only done *once* so it's only a one time expensive operation

Comment: If you google a history about URLs, Java had a limited hashCode before :)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by limiting the no of characters to be considered for creating hash code ?

Comment: @dehasi I didn't know that. Do you have some link to share? My attempts to google it were not very fruitful :(

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Let's say that you have String which has 100 mln characters. If you have limit hashCode will end quickly. If you don't (as in original implementation) then it will iterate over 100 mln characters without any big benefit.

Comment: @LLL Can you think of some operations which will be faster if the hashcode is created with lesser no of characters ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande well basically every operation which calls hashCode :) For example putting something to HashTable with String key or maybe some custom sorting methods.

Comment: @dehasi it's not very clear from the article you've shared as it was rather issue with URL which probably only used hashCode and didn't check equals later but I get the idea, so thanks!

Comment: @LLL Imagine same hashcode being generated for a lot of similar strings. Data structures like Hashmap & Hashset that rely on hashcode try to provide O(1) lookups. So if a lot of keys are mapped to the same bucket, a lot of strings will have to be compared before actually returning the matching result. So instead of comparing multiple strings character by character don't you think it is ok to iterate over a string once to generate a better hashcode. Generating better hashcode won't avoid string comparison, it will just reduce the possibility of strings ending up in the same buckets.

Comment: I think you can also benchmark results with both hashCode methods and see which works out better.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande your argument would be perfectly valid if String hashCode function would generate at least "decent" results but it doesn't, so in my opinion there is no point in investing more computation power and computing milions of characters to get "better hashes". For example "Aa" has same hash as "BB", "Ba" has same hash as "CB", "Ca" has same hash as "DB" and so on.

Comment: @LLL agreed. Though should you be storing millions of characters long String as a key in Hashmap ?

Comment: @dehasi the "URL equals" problem wasn't / isn't related to hashCode method. Java didn't limit hashCode. the "URL equals" problem is specific to URLs, and unrelated to the String representation. (URLs are/where considered equal if they point to the same location).

Comment: @LLL Eventually I found the story about java string hash and URLs.  The book is `The practice of programming` chapter `2.9 Hash Tables`, Kernighan & Pike.

Comment: @dehasi thanks, I've checked it and indeed URLs example is mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several possible reasons spring to mind:

1. It is common for Strings to vary only at the start or end, e.g. all StackOverflow question URLs start with "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/". Limiting the hashCode to only a subset of characters will therefore cause unnecessary collisions, and for some sets of strings cause many collisions. Your proposed algorithm would cause every stackoverflow question URL to have the same hashCode!
2. hashCode is fast and memoized, it's not clear that limiting the hashCode to some constant length will bring noticeable performance improvements, especially since it is always preceded by creating the String (an O(n) operation), and often followed by a call to `equals` (also O(n)).
3. Legacy reasons. [String.hashcode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) is specified to use a specific algorithm. Existing applications rely on this specification. Even if this optimisation was now deemed necessary it couldn't be made without breaking backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for answer. As to #1 I get the idea, although I think some reasonable limit e.g. 1024 should be enough to solve most of such issues. Or maybe some fancy code which would always get 32 characters but not always first 32. For bigger strings it could get 1st, 1000th, 2000th and etc (could be done with modulo). As to #2 I'm not saying it will bring noticeable benefit but since hash codes are lazy computed even if creating String is O(n) then why not have potentially better hashCode implementation? As to #3 I agree that changing it now might be problematic but I was just curious.

Comment: Anyway you've summarized couple potential reasons, so I'll accept your answer, thanks!